# Blog posts won't open on my custom WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

This could be a dumb question, but I just can't figure it out. I'm working on a custom WordPress theme I created by converting a html website. But when I use WP_Query, it doesn't load my blog posts. Yes, it displays a list of blog posts as it should with the loop, but when I click on each title or the 'read more' link of a post, it only changes the url in the address bar to the link of the post and then simply refreshes the hope page. It doesn't open I'm really tired. Here's the query loop in my index.php

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories(); 

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {


    //define args for query
    $args = array(
    'cat' => $category->term_id,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '30',
);
//The main query

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

    <section class="<?php echo $category->name; ?> listing">
        <h2>Latest in <?php echo $category->name; ?>:</h2>

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();
            ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'category-listing' ); ?>>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
</a>
                <?php } ?>

                <h3 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </h3>

                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </article>

<?php } // end while ?>

    </section>

<?php } // end if

// Use reset to restore original query.
wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>

                </div><!-- blog-main-content-->


                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

                                <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please what do I do

Comment: Do you have a `single.php` file in your theme to use as a template for the posts? Which file do you have this code in?

Comment: No, the code is in my index.php. I don't have a template file yet for posts.  Must I create one?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, you are missing a template file for your posts page. In your current configuration, the posts loop will be displayed on all pages of your website since you only have an `index.php` file. You should create a `single.php` template to display your single blog posts.

Here is the WordPress template hierarchy for reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/